How is the squared error here an integral?
I ended up somewhat confused at this paper where they minimise the Squared Loss (squared error) and write

From what I understand the basis would be the Cramer von mises criterion (seen this in StatsSE as well.) but then they just used the name without really calling it correctly; although I get this is basically replacing the sum for an integral.
Is the linked document the reason why they use that formula, or is there any other explanation/reason ?
